# Can we send different emails to user and admin at once using single event in laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, events, laravel-8, event-listener

I am creating a leave request application for employee in an organization where user can create a leave request and admin(s) can approve/reject the request. The user and admin(s) should receive mail each time after making a leave request and after approval too. I am using event listener to send the mail and could send the mail using separate events and listeners(4 **events**:

1. making leave request to admin,
2. making leave request to user,
3. after accepting/rejecting the request to admin and
4. accepting/rejecting the request to user

and likewise 4 **listeners** too)

but it would be better if I could reduce the number of events and listeners in this case since the user mail and email template only are different.
I studied about event subscribers which subscribe to multiple events from within the subscriber class itself which is not what I want.
Is it possible to send multiple emails to multiple user/admin using less number of **events/listeners**?
I am using laravel 8

Code:

controller is:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
          {
                DB::beginTransaction();
                try{
                    $request->validate(
                        [
                            'leave_type'      =>  'in:halfday,fullday',
                            'start_date'      =>  'required',
                            'end_date'        =>  'required',
                            'assignee'        =>  'required',
                        ]
                    );
        
                    $datetime1 = new \DateTime($request->start_date);
                    $datetime2 = new \DateTime($request->end_date);
                    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                    $days = $interval->format('%a');//total requested days
        
                    $leave_request= new LeaveRequest();
        
                    $leave_request->requested_by = auth()->user()->id;
                    $leave_request->leave_type_id = $request->leave_type_id ;
                    $leave_request->leave_type = $request->leave_type;
                    $leave_request->start_date = $request->start_date;
                    $leave_request->end_date =  $request->end_date;
                    $leave_request->total_days = $days+1;
                    $leave_request->assignee  = $request->assignee;
                    $leave_request->reviewer  = $request->reviewer;
                    
                    if($leave_request->save()){
                        $user = User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
        
                        $assignee = User::where('id',$request->assignee)->first();
                        $assignee->locale = App::currentLocale();
                        $assignee->requested_by = $user->name;
                        event(new SendLeaveRequestToAdminEvent($assignee));//send mail to admin asignee
                        
                        if($request->reviewer !=null){
                            $reviewer = User::where('id',$request->reviewer)->first();
                            $reviewer->locale = App::currentLocale();
                            $reviewer->requested_by = $user->name;
                            event(new SendLeaveRequestToAdminEvent($reviewer));//send mail to admin reviewer(optional)
                        }
                        
                        $user->locale = App::currentLocale();
                        event(new SendLeaveRequestToUserEvent($user));//send mail to user
                        DB::commit();
                        return response()->json([
                            'message'=> 'Leave requested successfully',
                            'status_code' => 200,
                        ]);
                    }
                    else{
                        DB::rollback();
                        return response()->json([
                            'status_code' => '204',
                            'message' => 'Leave request failed',
                        ]);
                    }
        
                } catch (Exception $error) {
                    DB::rollback();
                    return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'Leave request failed',
                    'error' => $error
                    ]);
               
 }
        }
```

first event to mail to admin(s) i.e; assignee and reviewer after sending leave request is

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\User;

class SendLeaveRequestToAdminEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $admin;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $admin)
    {
        $this->admin = $admin;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

second event to mail to user after sending leave request is

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\User;

class SendLeaveRequestToUserEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

first listener to admin(s):

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\LeaveRequestAdmin;
use App\Events\SendLeaveRequestToAdminEvent;

class SendLeaveRequestToAdminListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  SendLeaveRequestToAdminEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SendLeaveRequestToAdminEvent $event)
    {
        $email = $event->admin->email;
        Mail::to($email)->locale($event->admin->locale)->send(new LeaveRequestAdmin($event->admin));
    }
}
```

second listener to user:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\LeaveRequestUser;
use App\Events\SendLeaveRequestToUserEvent;

class SendLeaveRequestToUserListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  SendLeaveRequestToUserEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SendLeaveRequestToUserEvent $event)
    {
        $email = $event->user->email;
        Mail::to($email)->locale($event->user->locale)->send(new LeaveRequestUser($event->user));
    }
}
```

mail to admin:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class LeaveRequestAdmin extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $admin;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($admin)
    {
        $this->admin = $admin;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('email.leaverequestadmin', [
            'url' => URL::to('/home'),
            'admin' => $this->admin,
        ])->subject('Incoming Leave Request');
    }
}
```

mail to user:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class LeaveRequestUser extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('email.leaverequestuser', [
            'url' => URL::to('/home'),
            'user' => $this->user,
        ])->subject('Leave Request Received');
    }
}
```

the above code is used after leave request is created which have two separate events/listeners/mail/ blade templates. Like wise I have similar another two events/listeners/mail/ blade templates each which are used after the leave request is accepted/rejected.

Comment: Glad to help, but please share any code you have. Is it possible? Sure, you can do it in a million ways, but nobody here will write the entire code base you need, so share what you have and people will help you from there.

Comment: @dz0nika I have added the code above.

Comment: "Is it possible to send multiple emails to multiple user/admin" - yeah, of course. You can send as many mails as you like per listener